# How to configure job with alternating parameters in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I do have a list of around 20 parameters for a current jenkins job. I need to configure a job that is able to insert those parameters in a slightly alternating way. Example:

[job 1]:
param-a = "foo-20", param-b = "bar-20"

[job 2]:
param-a = "foo-21", param-b = "bar-21"

Since I have around 80 builds that need their parameters alteranted in that way, I was wondering if there is a solution to only create one job and tell jenkins, how to alternate the values of the parameters. I don't want to mess up my jenkins dashboard with 80 builds of the very same kind. 
I also need to use the deployment plugin, to deploy a build under a different context path. 
Is there any way to achive such a setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use the "Build Env Propagator Plugin"
It allows you to change an environment var during the build.

Combine it with the "Conditional BuildStep Plugin" to decide in which case to run the "Build Env Propagator" and it might be a good solution for you

Comment: Thanks! Going to try that. I'll let you know if it works for me.